# How to use eval-defun in emacs config?

Tags: org-mode, init-file

I'm encountering this bug invalid org-encode-time.
https://www.mail-archive.com/emacs-orgmode@gnu.org/msg146267.html

The bug fixed if I open defun-org-matcher file then use command eval-defun.
But the problem exist again if I reclose emacs, and I need to re eval-defun org-matcher again.

Is there a way to automate evaluating defun?
I try to use this in my config but it show error.
(eval-defun 'org-matcher-time)

Answer (score 0):

The bug is gone after I update emacs to 28.2 and update doom emacs.

Comment: You don't specify what Emacs and Doom versions you used, which manifested the "bug". Please do that, otherwise the Q&A are not so helpful for others.